# Similarity measure for non-binary user preference vector

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, recommender-system, cosine-similarity

Cosine similarity can be used to measure the similarity between two vectors that encode the user preferences with the following values:

- 0: No user feedback (e.g. the user never viewed a merchandise)
- 1: Positive user feedback
- -1: Negative user feedback

So the similarity between two users can be: `cosine_similarity([1, 0, 0, -1], [-1, 1, 0, -1])`.

However, what can be done if I want to introduce another state for "user viewed this merchandise, but has neutral (neither positive nor negative) feedback", and I want the following interactions between the 4 states:

- no feedback & anything: not similar or dissimilar (0)
- neutral & neutral: similar (+1)
- neutral & positive: similar (+1)
- neutral & negative: similar (+1)
- positive & positive: very similar (+2)
- negative & negative: very similar (+2)
- positive & negative: dissimilar (-2)

I can't seem to achieve this with simple cosine similarity. Is there any well-established method for doing this?

`some_similarity_measure([neutral, no feedback, positive], [negative, negative, negative])`?